# Unable to call Ion infinite scroll method present in angular controller from with ionic fancy select directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic multi select directive, I want to do pagination. So, I used the ion-infinte-scroll. I added the ion-infinte-scroll in fancy select directive. But, when I scroll down method present in controller is not getting called.

Added the below code in fancy select directive.
In fancy select directive.js (line no 115 and 116)

```
<ion-infinite-scroll immediate-check="false"
  on-infinite="scrollDown()" distance="5%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

In script.js

```
$scope.scrollDown = function(){
   console.log('function triggered'); 
}
```

I have created a plunker for this https://plnkr.co/edit/ZlhZOZVcDGuIxRyEtCfv?p=preview. Kindly, help me through.

Comment: Let's start by a basic check, your function's name may have a conflict with some inner scope's fields of the directive. So try first : $scope.ctrlScope={};$scope.ctrlScope.scrollDown = function(){}. And in the html : on-infinite="ctrlScope.scrollDown()". Can't load plnkr at the moment

Comment: I tried adding $scope.ctrlScope={};$scope.ctrlScope.scrollDown = function(){} in script.js but still I am unable to invoke the method available in controller. Updated plunker url https://plnkr.co/edit/ZlhZOZVcDGuIxRyEtCfv?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected some errors in your directive, for example this line was missing:

```
 modalScope.scrollMethod = scrollMethod;
```

and there was another error in retrieving the scrollMethod attribute:

```
scrollMethod = attrs.scrollMethod,
```

Besides in HTML the attribute must be `scroll-method`: camelCase on JS side, dash separator on HTML side.

Then the `scrollMethod()` function must be in the modal scope not in the controller, or you can do inherit modal scope from parent controller (but it is not the case of your modal service). Another possibility is to add the method to `$rootScope`.

Here is a plunker updated:

https://plnkr.co/edit/3CK1wUEQustmkEPoJBqG?p=preview

Comment: is it not possible to call  myScrollDown frm modalScope.myScrollDown method.

Comment: so attach the myScrollDown method to $rootScope in your controller and the game is done! plunker updated

Comment: got stuck up in another issue. https://plnkr.co/edit/ZlhZOZVcDGuIxRyEtCfv?p=preview .  The new elements is getting added to the scope when I scroll but not showing in modal. Can you check the updated plunker. Need to close the modal and see the updated scope elements.

Comment: You missed another thing: to observe for `scope.items` change... Your directive doesn't update automatically the list in your modal, it needs a `scope.$watch('items', ...)` and inside this function you have to update `modalScope.selection.selectable = scope.items;`

Comment: I newly updated my plunker... https://plnkr.co/edit/3CK1wUEQustmkEPoJBqG?p=preview

Comment: Ion-inifnte-scroll is not calling more that once. If I pull down the method is not getting called. I even tried increasing the distance and checked but the method is not getting invoked second time. Added $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');